# How to extract type of Array member inside of member of Interface?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

How do i extract the type of key3 in MyInterface2 for use in key3Value similar to key2Value?

```
interface MyInterface {
    key1: {
        key2: string
    }
}

const key2Value: MyInterface['key1']['key2'] = 'Hi' //Works fine

interface MyInterface2 {
    key1: {
        key2: Array<{ key3: string }>
    }
}

const key3Value: MyInterface2['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'Hi' //Property 'key3' does not exist on type '{ key3: string; }[]'.(2339)
```

Link to [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkBrCdARgC5CSynL0AmegZzClAHNHSAXyLCiCAPYguFKqwBqcADYBXCPQzZIsRBADaAchbV9AXQMtWp5AF5k+gBLB9RIqC14UGnNqSsGzKjp-JjILegBBKCg4dAAeAhl0AGZObj5kQQA+AQyRFwkpMESkhRU1NCxvD1ZzQNNatnrDKiSrWwcnIA).

Comment: `MyInterface2['key1']['key2']` is an array, so you would need to index it like `const key3Value: MyInterface2['key1']['key2'][0]['key3'] = 'Hi'`

Comment: Related (though not dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376468/how-to-get-type-of-array-type-values

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an index to get into the array:

```
const key3Value: MyInterface2['key1']['key2'][0]['key3'] = 'Hi'
```