# TypeScript types from array to object

Tags: typescript

I have array where each item is array `[name: string, someFunction: Function]`. I would like to convert it to object, where keys are `name`s and values are `someFunction`s:

```
// Input
const arrayFunctions = [
    ['getLength', (text: string) => text.length],
    ['setValue', (id: string, value: number) => {}],
    ['getAll', () => ([1, 2, 3])]
]

// Output
const objectFunctions = {
    getLength: (text: string) => text.length,
    setValue: (id: string, value: number) => {},
    getAll: () => ([1, 2, 3])
}
```

Is there any way to connect type of function in input array and type of function in output object?

```
type ObjectFunctions<ArrayFunctions> = { [/* Value from ArrayFunctions[i][0] */]: /* Value from ArrayFunctions[i][1] */ }

const arrayToObject = <ArrayFunctions extends Array<any>>(functions: ArrayFunctions) => {
    const result = {}

    for (const [name, func] of functions) {
        result[name] = func
    }

    return result as ObjectFunctions<ArrayFunctions>
}

const arrayFunctions = [
    ['getLength', (text: string) => text.length],
    ['setValue', (id: string, value: number) => {}],
    ['getAll', () => ([1, 2, 3])]
]

const objectFunctions = arrayToObject(arrayFunctions)

const length = objectFunctions.getLength() // Should be error because first parameter (text) is missing.
objectFunctions.setValue(true, 2) // Should be error, because of first parameter (id) must be string.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible if the array is defined at compile time, so typescript will have a chance to infer the types.

**Convert inner tuple to object**:

```
type ToObject<T> = T extends readonly [infer Key, infer Func]
  ? Key extends PropertyKey
  ? { [P in Key]: Func } : never : never;
```

This will allow us to convert `['getLength', (text: string) => text.length]`
To `{ getLength: (text: string) => number }`

**Convert array of tuples to array of objects** ([mapped type on array](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063)):

```
type ToObjectsArray<T> = {
  [I in keyof T]: ToObject<T[I]>
};
```

This will allow us to convert array of arrays to array of objects.
We can now extract union of desired objects by [querying the type of array item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376468/how-to-get-type-of-array-type-values/46387055#46387055) `Array[number]`.

The last step - we actually need intersection instead of union. We can use the famous [UnionToIntersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/1113002):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
```

**Combine all together**:

```
// @ts-ignore
type FunctionMap<ArrayFunctions> = UnionToIntersection<ToObjectsArray<ArrayFunctions>[number]>;
```

Ignore above needed because typescript forgets that it produces array when using mapped type on array type.

---

OK, let's test:

```
const arrayToObject = <ArrayFunctions extends ReadonlyArray<any>>(functions: ArrayFunctions) => {
  const result: any = {}

  for (const [name, func] of functions) {
    result[name] = func
  }

  return result as FunctionMap<ArrayFunctions>
}

const arrayFunctions = [
  ['getLength', (text: string) => text.length],
  ['setValue', (id: string, value: number) => { }],
  ['getAll', () => ([1, 2, 3])]
] as const;

const objectFunctions = arrayToObject(arrayFunctions);

const l = objectFunctions.getLength() // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
objectFunctions.setValue(true, 2) // Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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)

Comment: I've tried to convert `type TT = [x: string, y: number]` to `type TT = {x: string, y: number}` by using `type TT = ToObject<[x: string, y: number]>;` but it yields only `type TT = { [x: string]: number; }`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @danivicario yes, you have completely different requirement. You have a labeled tuple which is equivalent to `[string, number]`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Your solution is amazing and has inspired me to learn more about Typescripts type system. Thank you for that. 
I wonder if it is possible to constrain the second element of the array to only accept functions?

Comment: @bennidi do you mean when we create `const arrayFunctions = ...`?

Comment: Yes. That's the part where I am failing to rewrite the typings such that the second element of the tuple is only allowed to be of type XY.

Comment: Found a way: ```<U extends any, T extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [string, U]>>(args: T)```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Typescript compiler cannot guess types dynamically(at runtime).

In typescript, advanced types like `ReturnType` or `InstanceType` are only allowed to guess already defined types.

Answer (score -2):

This same problem has been plaguing me for days. Though, with `TypeScript@4.4.4`, this is possible with a custom typedef:

```js
type ArrayToObject<Arr extends any[]> = {
    [Entry in keyof Arr as string]: Arr[Entry];
};
```

And you could use like:

```js
type FuncParamsToObj<Func extends (...args: any[]) => any> = ArrayToObject<Parameters<Func>>;

type myFunc = ( a: string, b?: { x?: number, y?: object } ) => string;

const paramObj: FuncParamsToObj<myFunc> = {
    a: 1,
    b: { x: 7, y: { w: 'hi' }},
};
```