# Generic type to convert array/tuple of objects to object keyed by property

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following:

```
type Field = {
  _id: string;
  value: string;
}

const fields = [
  { _id: 'a', value: '2' },
  { _id: 'b', value: '3' }
] as const;
```

I would like to define a `type ValueById<T extends readonly [...Field[]]>` which produces:

```
{
  a: '2',
  b: '3',
}
```

I've gotten partially to where I want to be with this:

```
export type ValueById<T extends readonly [...Field[]]> = {
  [Z in T[number]['_id']]: T[number]['value']
}

type NewType = ValueById<typeof fields>
```

But unfortunately this produces a type of:

```
{
  a: '2' | '3'
  b: '2' | '3'
}
```

Is there a way to narrow down the type of the values here?

Comment: Is `{ a: '2' } & { b: '3' }` good enough? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmEYF4YB5SRQB8A2gFAwwDeMA+gmgFwwDkAhiwDQwBubKAVyTMWAJhYwAvpwrU6DEQCMuvfkJEBmCZLIBdMmSgBPAA5IYAMWToIAFVPmcxsyDjxrGANyGHlj9j9UDHszEjABAFtFJAAnXW8fMxgASTQANTUkAFUwBHBcWyIA2xgkAA8oJDAMQPQYAH45EgAtGAQwGFsSFno0Fl1dZi6WPkEkfqkYZjAkHliE53McvLBbEGSwSpiIJGAoFdwsoqxZAAos0oqqmrYwIwaYU4BrZiyASmwinhAGKZgZuYxD7lSrVTCnZ7MdpwWIpD5YL4-NAfRrJP4A+YGcomEAxWCLGAZMYAISMqQCy3Aaw2Wx2ewOqSJQkpYFwViCRCInhgAHoeXI2CJxJMAGRyRSabQGFBIWBwEAgZhMpCk8k4GiC1jibgS1haKRAA

Comment: Oooh, super close. Might be good enough for my use case. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll need to extract [array item type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387055/1113002):

```
const fields = [
  { _id: 'a', value: '2' },
  { _id: 'b', value: '3' }
] as const;

type Field = typeof fields[number];
// {
//     readonly _id: "a";
//     readonly value: "2";
// } | {
//     readonly _id: "b";
//     readonly value: "3";
// }
```

Now we can create a union of "id-value" pairs using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```
type IdValueUnion<T> = T extends Field ? { [Z in T['_id']]: T['value'] } : never;
// IdValueUnion<Field>
//
// {
//     a: "2";
// } | {
//     b: "3";
// }
```

We're pretty close, but we need [intersection instead of union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/1113002):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
// UnionToIntersection<IdValueUnion<Field>>
// {
//     a: "2";
// } & {
//     b: "3";
// }
```

Last step is "compact" the intersection by just remapping keys to values:

```
export type Compact<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

export type ValueById = Compact<UnionToIntersection<IdValueUnion<Field>>>;
// 
// {
//     a: "2";
//     b: "3";
// }

let foo: ValueById = { a: '2', b: '3' }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmEYF4YG0BQMMA3jAPoJoBcMA5AIa0A0MAbvSgK5I20BMtGAF8mhEuUq8ARszYduvAMyCh+ALox6mUJCgBufPigBPAA5IYAMWTpsME+ZBx4NjLjCcAtlKQAnNQYA9IEk+MFEEb5I9GjgKMYS1DAARPTJQSERMFExcQnsXDwpfOlhIUIwAD6h4Vk5sWDxiTTJUqW1kdENTQUKKYrt5YYOFgCSaABq8kgAqmAI4AA8ACoAfHbLMEgAHlBIYBhWrjAA-OK4AFowCGAwy7i0FGi0amo097S9SC-CMDRgSFYfgyMHGU0KcwWYEW1lQaFWZTKNUyEXoLRKIIq1WISKyUhaA0xwzMFkh4GWIFGYD2vggSGAUChixm6ywYgAFDMtrt9od6GAEmd2QBrGgzACU2HWrBAlD+MABQN8kp2ewOmHZIpoNzgflBkqw0tlaElZ1G8sVwKRZLAFKpNLpDKZYOmNphrlWCPCOI6RDRxUGvwAZMisjB8f1A6p8DtTCBfLARjAAMIgTymegMlas84AaWut2FSGMTjubzuuFzGiEBhj2zjCfsJJg4O4ACFjOM7Kn05moMz5uTKdS-I7GUsXRDB9DYehPasQYAeDcAkftIn0ov3owN4glRwwoJCwOAgEA0VtIDtdnCkf38WQR2jKYRAA)

Comment: Nice, that compact trick is great! Very good to know