# How to check that argument key is listed in generic type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I just started to use TypeScript with ReactJS. I want to declare component props in this way:

```ts
type TProps<T> = {
  data: {
    [key in T]: string // key should be listed on <T>
  }[]
  columns: {
    header: string
    name: // should be listed in <T>
  }[]
}
const Component = <T extends string[]>(props: TProps<T>) => {
  //some code here
}
```

In this case I receive an error about `T is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'`

How can I define it? The main idea is that user should pass array of names for columns as generic, and then if he passes props for component with name which is not listed in generic it should show an error.

Example:

```ts
const Table = <T extends string[]>(props) => {
  // code
}

// valid
Table<["name", "email"]>({
  data: [
    {
      name: "Alex",
      email: "alex@mail.com"
    },
    {
      name: "George",
      email: "george@mail.com"
    }
  ],
  columns: [
    {
      header: 'Name',
      dataColumn: 'name'
    },
    {
      header: 'E-Mail',
      dataColumn: 'email'
    }
  ]
});

// not valid
Table<["name", "email"]>({
  data: [
    {
      name: "Alex",
      email: "alex@mail.com"
    },
    {
      name: "George", // no email property
    }
  ],
  columns: [
    {
      header: 'Name',
      dataColumn: 'name'
    },
    {
      header: 'Phone',
      dataColumn: 'phone' // phone property not listed in generic type
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to generic type parameter so it will only accept list of valid key types:

```
type TProps<T extends PropertyKey[]> = {
    data: {
        [key in T[number]]: string
    }[]
    columns: {
        header: string
        dataColumn: T[number]
    }[]
}
```

Now it behaves as expected:

```
Table<["name", "email"]>({
    data: [
        {
            name: "Alex",
            email: "alex@mail.com"
        },
        {
            name: "George", // Property 'email' is missing in type ...
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        {
            header: 'Name',
            dataColumn: 'name'
        },
        {
            header: 'Phone',
            dataColumn: 'phone' // Type '"phone"' is not assignable to type '"name" | "email"'
        }
    ]
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgCgJwPZgM4B4ZQgD2BAOwBNUpEUIFQBpCEAbQF0A%20KAXigG8BYAKCgFQiAQ2DCAXFz6CZUegGs6UAJYFY9AgFcAtgCNKjRpNTAEqgObTBAXyZWBAYyQAbHQVSSe-WQIAWEYSJKY1MLe1kRMQBhFzdJGA0dfQRGcNtU3ms%20Pid3YFhhXWdoDkxsPEISKBMzAnMmZgAKMGQ0ePI0TGYASnZWLxkAekGoJyC%20LN4%20YagAN2FnZSI%20GELi9HoAIgJhbQhNgBooTYhtYWVnTZZGgcFIiTlwmVufGR29yU2AQWKcQ6fXqdzs5PgtcAABM4XAB0Tm0mwBAmsB0RUm8r0E7wgnwA4hAkAhzPsUeiMdgoSDjkSCUTIcDYUh4ajJjJGCSZE5XNp3JJ6KiXmT-IFglAAOQAOV2EFF7LJAnuMS5BEkoqxouZsp8AoxQqCCBVAFEALQAWWBMtRMgVsW5KqBF3VpJkLMEGWs3QA3NleDMCEh8vNFsteKsihANtspYdjvbLtcBfdefzLZipZ8frh-k7ARTQb86TC4Qjs0jNbJta8sbj8YTiVAZh1KKAxbHRSpSNplKhUBYVGpQJAoNDh8zwmzwpy3B5HiW0XK-AE9SrJXsLbOraJhIq4mK1Rrk%20vBLqRaK4L4kARpWWMdalSqwOfL22ZjBwNBRZsHxf9m2u1A-fkwjdso5g7GGUDAEgEFvmKkZ7JsUAAD4xhSmyOhiLoCG6npAA)

---

We use `T[number]` to get union type of allowed keys ([array/tuple item type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387055/1113002))

---

`data` definition can be simplified using [Record utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

```
type TProps<T extends PropertyKey[]> = {
    data: Record<T[number], string>[]
    columns: {
        header: string
        dataColumn: T[number]
    }[]
}
```