# TS create keys of new type from array of strings

Tags: typescript

I simply want to maintain an array of values that dynamically scales the type definition of FiatExchangeRates.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
const currencies = ['eur', 'usd', 'gbp', 'chf'] as const;

type FiatExchangeRates = {
    // ... how to get the following?
    // eur: number,
    // usd: number,
    // gbp: number,
    // chf: number,
}

const fiatExchangeRates: FiatExchangeRates = {
  eur: 1.11,
  usd: 1.12,
  gbp: 1.13,
  chf: 1.14,
};

const a = fiatExchangeRates.eur;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract [tuple member type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376468/how-to-get-type-of-array-items) and use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to create a desired one:

```
type FiatExchangeRates = { [K in (typeof currencies)[number]] : number }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCuAnRBTMwCWKIwLwwG0ByFJIgGhiPggBMKqBzAIwAcGjgALAMyIF0YAQxyhIUANwAoKVACerFDABiGIVACiAD25CwjFACV12PDADehANIwMYGAAp5ikDzhJU6LBACUBMPAAtswoiPz8AFwwAcGhMAC%20MmLQMDxqmjpcegbGUNhRqurauvpGJjj45lIwMKSIUQCMAHQNDeTVMDS0jS0ATO01LKw9DQDMA3C8IwAs7fHSUsmwQmZpRZnZZXkQTXUSQA)

Comment: wow thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: Do you know to also convert the `currencies` const into a new type like this:

`type Currency = 'eur' | 'usd' | 'gbp' | 'chf'`

Comment: `type Currency = (typeof currencies)[number]` already part of the answer  . `type FiatExchangeRates = { [C in Currency]: number }`

Comment: coooool :) thanks