# Derive Type from Array Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

I have an array

```
const frequencyOptions = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'];
```

I need to set Typescript Type to another array that can contain values from the options array only like

```
let frequencyValues = ['Daily', 'Weekly'] // can be any combination of options array
```

Comment: You did not mention what is your problem.

Comment: I need to set the typescript type of the values array so that it can only accept values that are only available in the  frequencyOptions array.

Comment: Do you control options array creation? `frequencyOptions`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yes, the `frequencyOptions` array will be mostly constant/static

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Define a union type from an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085454/typescript-define-a-union-type-from-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're controlling options array creation you can:

```
const frequencyOptions = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'] as const;
type Option = typeof frequencyOptions[number]; // "Daily" | "Weekly" | "Monthly"

let frequencyValues: Option[] = ['Daily', 'Weekly'];

// Expect error
frequencyValues = ['foo'] // Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"Daily" | "Weekly" | "Monthly"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwKYEcCuSzAJ4HkAOUAluBDALwwDaA5ACICGRANtjQDQw0DqSSA1qw5cAsuCgALIQF0YDMqEhQA3ACgo2fEhgFipCjA1aQceMnSYcukpCpg0AWwBGSBNOUwA9J5gAiRizYvjAAPn68AqzBYb5iYJJRqqrMSLCIqBhY2ABqDMwYEABcOoQ2EFSylLQBQpw8fIJs7kneMACiAB5awLCuCCAIqukWWbn5SGRVNHAgIDSyrQAqmto0vjMgvjQwRGRgILDyEEQA5mAMTimGIIYrXP5MUaHhDU8xcQlBNAB0QA)

---

`as const` [prevents literal types widening](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to `string`, then we [query tuple item type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387055/1113002).